# How to find a crash report from an Android device?

Tags: android, crash

I am developing android application for client. Now client testing my application in various device. While testing, my application is crash at times. Now I need to know when and where the application crash.

How can I get the crash report from the device? Since my client does not have sdk and eclipse to view logcat error report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are mechanisms like [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) that will let you obtain the crash reports from Android apps.

Comment: whether the logcat will not store in device? whether i have to get the logcat by installing ACRA application in my device.

Comment: The device will have the logcat. If you need to fetch the logcat from the device, you will need to use [adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html). ACRA is a library that you will have to use in your application for it to send the crash reports (either by uploading to Google Docs or as email)

Answer (score 2):

[Instabug](https://instabug.com/) is a bug & crash reporting service and it’s just what you’re looking for. 
It automatically sends a report containing all crash and device details once a crash occurs, plus it only takes a line of code to integrate in your app.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the [Crash Report SDK](https://github.com/liu-yanjun/crash-log-report) in the project, You can view the released application crash log, which will help to locate problems.

Here is a [demo page](http://www.crashlog.org/log_list.jsp?package_name=org.crashlog.sample)